# .Net Maui copying assets into appData

Tags: .net, maui

Tring to move a PDF file from `Resources\Raw` to `appData` directory for App. File becomes corrupted on copy. Obviously I'm missing something.

using the following:

```
  using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("CBA2015.pdf");
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        if (stream != null)
        {
            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "CBA2015.pdf");

            using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
            using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);

            await streamWriter.WriteAsync(contents);

        }
```

Comment: please [edit] your question so your code is formatted and readable

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```cs
string sourceFile = "CBA2015.pdf";
// Read the source file
//using Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(sourceFile);
// using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);

string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "CBA2015.pdf");
using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
using Stream fs = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(sourceFile);
using BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(outputStream);
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    var bytesRead = 0;
                
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] bytes;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (fs)
    {
        do
        {
             buffer = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
             bytesRead = buffer.Count();
             writer.Write(buffer);
        }

        while (bytesRead > 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Esset Thanks for the code, it works great, but do you have any idea how to test for the existence of the ```sourceFile``` before beginning this operation? I've been trying to figure it out and just can't get it.  Thanks!

Comment: Something like this from .net 7,   if (File.Exists(sourcefile) {....}

Answer (score 0):

Finding out if the sourceFile exist:
await FileSystem.Current.AppPackageFileExistsAsync("sourceFile");