# How to bundle files in MAUI?

Tags: file-io, io, bundle, maui

I'm trying to access files in MAUI and I know I should bundle them but I don't know how to do it.
In what directory should I place the file?
When I bundle it, how should I write the path of the file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? In the process of implementation, which specific step went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

1. Place the files you want to bundle in Resources\Raw\ folder within your project.  I could not get other locations to work.
2. Mark the files with Build Action = MauiAsset, and select an option for Copy to Output Directory (always or newer)
3. access them by relative path only (so for most files you will only use the raw file name):

   using (Stream instream = FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(fileName))
4. read the contents with StreamReader or BinaryReader.

I needed to copy the files to my app data directory and what did NOT work was using a ByteArrayContent.ReadAsByteArray (it hangs) and instream.CopyToAsync (it also hangs).  To copy files you could use the approach described here:

[.Net Maui copying assets into appData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658809/net-maui-copying-assets-into-appdata)

Based on your comment, you don't want to use async, but there is only OpenAppPackageFileAsync available.

you could put this in an async function

```
async Task GetMyAssets() { ... }
```

then call it from a synchronous function like this:

```
GetMyAssets().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: What if I want to bundle an executable, and run it programmatically? I'm trying to bundle FFMpeg in the app and invoke it when I need it.

Comment: not sure that is possible.  can you not build ffmpeg as a library and link that into your application?

Comment: I actually managed to do it eventually, just by following the procedure in this answer. I simply bundled the exe as you recommend. Then I made a function invoked at the build stage (`CreateMauiApp()`) which simply reads the exe with a `BinaryReader`, then writes it into the `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory` with a `BinaryWriter`. The exe can be reached in the `AppDataDirectory` by other parts of the code and invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows#platform-differences) I linked to earlier

> Files that were added to the project with the Build Action of
> MauiAsset can be opened with this method. .NET MAUI projects will
> process any file in the Resources\Raw folder as a MauiAsset.

Using

```
FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync()
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use async?