# Sqlite data in is saved only on one device

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI app using the sqlite database. It turns out that the input data is stored only on one device.
If you turn on the app on another device, there will be no data in the app. What should I do to have the data displayed on any device? Is it possible to do this without redoing the entire program again?

My Model:

```cs
public class MuseumModels
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int MuseumID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Img_title { get; set; }
    public string Museum_Img { get; set; }     
}
```

My Service:

```cs
[Table("MuseumModels")]
public class MuseumService : IMuseumService
{
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _dbConnection;

    public MuseumService()
    {
        SetUpDb();
    }

    private async void SetUpDb()
    {
        if (_dbConnection == null)
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MuseumFinderDB.db3");
            _dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            await _dbConnection.CreateTableAsync<MuseumModels>();
            // await _dbConnection.CreateTableAsync<CollectionModel>();
        }
    }

    public Task<int> AddMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel)
    {
        return _dbConnection.InsertAsync(museumModel);
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel)
    {
        return _dbConnection.DeleteAsync(museumModel);
    }

    public async Task<List<MuseumModels>> GetMuseumList()
    {
        var museumList = await _dbConnection.Table<MuseumModels>().ToListAsync();

        return museumList;
    }

    public Task<int> UpdateMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel)
    {
        return _dbConnection.UpdateAsync(museumModel);
    }
}
```

My Interface:

```cs
public interface IMuseumService
{
    Task<List<MuseumModels>> GetMuseumList();

    Task<int> AddMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel);

    Task<int> DeleteMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel);

    Task<int> UpdateMuseum(MuseumModels museumModel);
}
```

Comment: You need to synchronize the data. A common approach is to use cloud-based real-time databases like Firebase or Azure, it cannot be done with simple on-device databases. BTW: Is this MAUI **or** Xamarin?

Comment: SQLite is a local db.  It does not magically sync for you.  Do you want every user of your app to have access to every other users data?

Comment: Here's a link to a possible solution using Firebase with MAUI: https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/realtime-database-with-firebase-in-net-maui-60323460ef7e. You'll potentially need to take care of user authentication and implement the logic to store data and listen to updates.

Comment: Are you trying to include a prefilled SQLite database with each instance of the app?  If so, then I use the code here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74672183/6188976) to copy my database from my Resources folder to the final application for each user.